# My Bash Script reads in and processes files very slow

Tags: arrays, performance, bash, file, shell

I'm working off of a Windows 7 box using cygwin (yea, I know but its all i have available).
I have a script that I am working on. Essentially it just reads in a text file.  The text file is very large (sometimes 500,000 lines) and contains a list of filenames (with spaces).
I have been reading in the file line by line, "processing" the line and copying the results to another file.

using something like this:

```
while read line; do
   x=${line:0:8)
   y=${line:9:2}
   if [[this is true]]; then
     #copy to new file
     echo "$line" >> "file2.txt"
   fi
done < "file.txt"
```

The issue that I have is that it takes FOREVER. To "process" 90,000 lines takes 4-5 hours.
By processing, it runs through 2 if statements.
I"m sure it'll "take what it'll take" as far as the amount of time but I'm just thinking of ways to make it faster.
I thought of potentially reading the entire file into an array, "process" the array and put results in another array, then export the entire array into a file. ??
That's my theory anyhow.

any suggestions

EDITED:

Here are a few more details.
My text file contains a list of filenames.
The filename consist of:
-"semi"-sequential prefix (the reason its "semi" is because if the server reboots, it starts over)
-dash
-timestamp (year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds)
-dash
-frame number

ex.

```
($inputfile)
02-20111012135454-00.jpg
03-20111012135548-00.jpg
01-20111012135643-01.jpg
02-20111012135645-00.jpg
```

Now I have to sort these pictures by date and if the server restarts then the prefix may start over so I can assume they are listed in order.  So what I do is use Sed to parse out the the full date/time and right to a new file ($unsortedfile) so what I do is

Here is the actual code:

```
while read line; do 
  echo "$line"   |sed 's#\([0-9]*\)\([-]\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{6\}\)\([-]\)\([0-9]*\)\([\.jpg]*\)#\3\4\5 \6 \7 \8 \1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9#'  >> "$unsortedfile"
done <  "$inputfile"
```

This is a VERY SLOW PROCESS.

ex.

```
($unsorted.txt)
20111012 135454 - 00 01-20111012135454-00.jpg
20111012 135548 - 00 01-20111012135548-00.jpg
20111012 135643 - 00 01-20111012135643-00.jpg
20111012 135645 - 00 01-20111012135645-00.jpg
20111017 130352 - 01 01-20111017130352-01.jpg
20111017 130354 - 00 01-20111017130354-00.jpg
20111017 130355 - 01 01-20111017130355-01.jpg
```

I then sort the text file using sort.

```
#Sort File by Date
sort  -n -k1,1n -k2,2n -k4,4n  "$unsortedfile" -no "$sortedfile"
```

This works well and is very fast.

Now, he'res the processing which consists of nested if then statements (which is probably more complex than it needs to be).
The goal is to only keep the filenames of the pictures within a certain time and day. For ex, Monday-Friday, 8am-4pm (such as work days) and I only want 1 picture minimum every 15 minutes.  This creates a new file ($noweekendfile) of just those filenames.

example:

```
while read -r line; do 
 imagename=${line:21:28}
 datevar=${line:0:8} 
 hourvar=${line:9:2}
 minutevar=${line:11:2}
 # trim leading zeros in hour.  ex. 08 becomes 8. Only if not midnight "00"
 if [[ "$hourvar" = "00" ]]; then
shorthourvar="0"
 else
shorthourvar="$(echo $hourvar | sed 's/0*//')"
fi  
if [[ $(date --date=$datevar +%u) -lt 6 ]] ; then
   if [[ "$shorthourvar" -gt "7" && "$shorthourvar" -lt "15" ]]; then 
      if [[ $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M --date "$datevar $hourvar:$minutevar") -gt $timelapsedatetime ]] ;then
   #Check to see if timestamp on filename is greater than timelapse
   # Only Run if it is a weekday and within the hours
           echo "$imagename" >> "$noweekendfile" 
   # Increase Timelapse by timelapsefrequency
   timelapsedatetime=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M --date "$datevar $hourvar:$minutevar  $timelapsefrequency minutes")
fi
  fi     
fi
done <  "$sortedfile"
```

This process is very slow.

So that's it.
Thank you greatly for the help!

Comment: Don't use bash if you need speed. Consider `awk` or perhaps something more native to Windows.

Comment: even better, use something like perl or ruby.  Bash is horrendously slow at processing large files like this.

Comment: If `true` is filled in for `this is true` then your code above takes only 3 _seconds_ for a 90.000 lines input file in bash (on my Linux box) - and about 20 seconds for 500.000 lines. (I created the input file using `yes|head -90000|nl|nl>file.txt`.)

Comment: Looking at your 3 "if" statements, I would try re-ordering them so the one you currently have second is done first, because that just checks a local variable ($shorthourvar) whereas the others exec the date command which will take longer, so you can avoid execing date for 16 hours in every 24.

Comment: You can also move the line that extracts "imagename" to just above the "echo" statement where you actually use it. And also move the extraction of the "minutevar" to just before the third "if" statement where you use it. You can also get rid of the "sed" and use Bash parameter substitution to drop the leading zero with "shorthourvar=${shorthourvar#0}"

Comment: You can also change the "echo ... >> noweekendfile" to a straightforward "echo" (without the append and filename) then add " > noweekendfile" to the very last line of the script to avoid keep opening and seeking the output file.

Comment: Your 3-line "sed" script could be speeded up a lot with a simple change. Instead of execing "sed" 500,000 times, once for each line and then opening, seeking and appending to an output file, change it to a single line with a single "sed" like this: sed "your funky code" inputfile > unsortedfile.

Comment: So for the "sed" you can import from a file and export the result right back to a file and it will do it on a line by line basis? So does it read the entire fire in first then process each line?

Comment: "sed" is the "Stream Editor" and it processes streams of data, so yes, it will process the file line by line without having to hold the entire thing in memory. Try it! Please let me know if all the changes speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment to your original post, this is really a use for which awk, python, perl, or perhaps even sed are the right tools for the job. Bash is intended for interaction and gluing together Unix/Linux commands to get any complex job accomplished -- though Bash enables quite a bit of basic programming capability in its own right.

Take a look at awk, it probably has the least learning curve to get to the solution you want:

[Awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

For many years, Jon Bentley wrote a column called, Programming Pearls, for the Communications of the ACM. In those columns, he addressed a number of programming problems using awk as the language in which he coded examples and solutions. Even if you never write a line of awk, these columns make an excellent read and are available in a series of books available on Amazon.com and elsewhere. To sample Programing Pearls, Second Edition, see:

[Programming Pearls, Second Edition](http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/)

Comment: OK, I haven't used Awk before. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: The script below runs in 4 seconds on my Windows XP box with a 90,000 line file created using [halfbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2747804/halfbit)'s method.

You might like to try VBScript as that is built-in to Windows, so you don't have to install anything  and it is fairly native. Here is an example, in which I just print every 10th line as I don't know what your "if" statement does. I would be intrigued to know how long it takes to run through your 90,000 lines:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Line,x,y,i

Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
   Line = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
   x=Mid(Line,1,8)  ' Extract 8 characters at start of line
   y=Mid(Line,10,2) ' Extract 2 more characters
   if i Mod 10=0 Then
      WScript.Echo Line
   End If
   i=i+1
Loop
```

Save the script as "process.vbs" then run it from a Command prompt like this:

```
cscript /nologo process.vbs < yourfile  > newfile
```

Comment: This looks interesting.  The reason that I was using linux (cygwin) is because I use rsync to copy the files from a linux server to a windows server.  So I was just staying in that environment.